# grunt watch batch tasks doesn't working

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Here's my Grunfile watch task:

```
watch: {
  jsFiles: {
    files: ['www/js/*.js','!www/js/*.min.js'],
    tasks: ['jshint','<%= pkg.jsTask %>'],
    options: {
        event: ['added', 'changed'],
        spawn: false
    }
  },
  cssFiles : {
    files : ['<%= pkg.cssTask === "less" ? "www/less/*.less" : "www/css/*.css" %>'],
    tasks : ['<%= pkg.cssTask %>'],
    options: {
        event: ['added', 'changed'],
        spawn: false
    }
  },
  pageFiles : {
    files: ['www/**.php','www/**.html'],
    tasks: ['<%= "uglify:some" === pkg.jsTask ? "dom_munger:whenSomeJs" : "dom_munger:whenAllInOneJs" %>','undoDomMungerQuoteShit'],
    options: {
        event: ['added', 'changed'],
        spawn: false
    }
  },
  otherFiles : {
    files: ['www/**','!www/**.php','!www/**.html','!www/js/*.js','!www/css/*.less','!www/css/*.css'],
    tasks: ['copy:regularFiles'],
    options: {
        event: ['added', 'changed'],
        spawn: false
    }
  },
  allFiles : {
    files: ['www/**'],
    options: {
        event: ['deleted'],
        spawn: false
    } 
  },
  ftpFiles : {
    files: ['build/**'],
    tasks: ['copy:ftp'],
    options: {
        event: ['added', 'changed'],
        spawn: false
    }
  },
  ftpDelete : {
    files: ['build/**'],
    options: {
        event: ['deleted'],
        spawn: false
    }
  }
}
```

All sub tasks place de processed file in the 'build' folder. All sub tasks, but one are working as expected: "ftpFiles"

This sub task look for changes in the 'build' folder. When I update some 'build' folder file manually, "ftpFiles" works. But when the changed file is updated by some other sub task, "ftpFiles" does not trigger.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please post your grunt config for running the watch task. Also post your grunt using the _verbose_ parameter.

Comment: I skip all the "Watching ... for changes", 'cause is too long: 

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\xampp\htdocs\swdesign\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\xampp\htdocs\swdesign\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.jsFiles.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.ftpFiles.files exists in config...OK
Watching www\js\swlib.js for changes.
...

Comment: >> File "www\js\swlib.js" changed.

Running "uglify:allInOne" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.allInOne exists in config...OK
Files: www/js/jquery.linkify-1.0-min.js, www/js/main.js, www/js/swlib.js -> build/js/sw.min.js
Options: banner="/*! SW Design 2014-06-07 */\r\n", footer="", compress={"drop_console":true}, mangle={}, beautify=false, report="min", flatten, wrap="SW"
Minifying with UglifyJS...Reading www/js/jquery.linkify-1.0-min.js...OK
Reading www/js/main.js...OK
Reading www/js/swlib.js...OK
OK
Writing build/js/sw.min.js...OK
File build/js/sw.min.js created: 13.82 kB ÔåÆ 6.82 kB

Comment: @PanGa I need it triggers 'ftpFiles' subtask since the js files changed in the 'build' folder, and it's the folder watched by 'ftpFiles'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need concurrent watchers to run.
You could either use [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) or [grunt-focus](https://github.com/joeytrapp/grunt-focus) to achieve that.

Follow below a *grunt-concurrent* example:

```
concurrent: {
  options: {
    logConcurrentOutput: true
  },
  dev: {
    tasks: ["watch:js", "watch:ftp"]
  }
}

grunt.registerTask("watch-dev", ["concurrent:dev"]);
```